# Preview pose mode when making change to armature in edit mode

Tags: animation, armature, bones

Is there any way preview how my pose will look like when I apply some changes to bones in edit mode, without switching back to pose mode ? I'm re-targeting some animations to different skeletons and sometimes I need to make adjustments to bone positions / rotations in edit mode. However when I make them in edit mode I don't have any way to preview what impact will it have on a final pose so right now I'm making small adjustment, switch back to pose mode to see how it looks like, and then back to edit mode again. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to view the same object in two different modes at the same time. I've never really had a problem with how blender handles this though, as tabbing between modes is quite quick. If you have to adjust your viewport every time you switch modes you could try having two viewports open with two different angles. Being able to view an animation while also being able to edit the skeleton would definitely be handy though.